# I can't install djangorestframework-simple-jwt

Tags: django-rest-framework

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement djangorestframework-simple-jwt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for djangorestframework-simple-jwt,

I've tried to upgrade pip but and after that i come again to install djangorestframework-simple-jwt, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```bash
 - python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip 
 - pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
```